# Kafka high fetch purgatory size

Tags: apache-kafka

I monitored our Kafka brokers and I saw our fetch purgatory size is `6K - 10K.`
what is the effect of high fetch purgatory size on the consumers?

Comment: In my case its around 50K-60K which mostly because fetch requests are waiting for data but wanted to understand the impact on broker.

Answer (score 3):

The size of fetch purgatory means how many fetch requests are being held by broker, waiting to be satisfied.

For example, consumer side has `fetch.min.bytes`, and `fetch.max.wait.ms`. A fetch request will be returned if either of the condition is met. Till then, it will sit in the purgatory pool, counted as purgatory size.

Therefore, high purgatory size simply means there are fetch request in wait status. It can have various causes and does not mean anything good or bad.

(Well, if you want, you can check if any consumer is having abnormally big fetch settings which causes the big purgatory size)

Good material to read:

1. https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-purgatory-hierarchical-timing-wheels/
2. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#monitoring

Comment: I doubt on this https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-purgatory-hierarchical-timing-wheels/
Still under proposal https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Purgatory+Redesign+Proposal right?

Comment: The design is merged https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1989. Nonetheless, the proposal is to optimize the internal implementation, but not to change purgatory's meaning. The explanation for purgatory stands.